# Android studio Can't create a new directory on sdcard?

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract, tess-two

I'm useing a library called scanlibrary to scan the photo and then pass it to tess-two to perform the OCR process. The problem is that the directory "ScanDemoExample" is not being created thus the tessdata files aren't copied and when I run my activity I get the error :

```
E/Tesseract(native): Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng!
```

because tesseract can't find the files in the data_path. 
The code works when I use an existing directory instead of the following :

```
public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/ScanDemoExample/";
```

**Here's my main activity:**

```
package com.scanner.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
import com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity;
import com.scanlibrary.ScanConstants;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.scanner.demo";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/ScanDemoExample/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";

   // public static final String _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";




    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 99;
    private Button scanButton;
    private Button cameraButton;
    private Button mediaButton;
    private ImageView scannedImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
        // You can get them at:
        // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
        // This area needs work and optimization
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }


        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new ScanButtonClickListener());
        cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new ScanButtonClickListener(ScanConstants.OPEN_CAMERA));
        mediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediaButton);
        mediaButton.setOnClickListener(new ScanButtonClickListener(ScanConstants.OPEN_MEDIA));
        scannedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scannedImage);

    }

    private class ScanButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private int preference;

        public ScanButtonClickListener(int preference) {
            this.preference = preference;
        }

        public ScanButtonClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startScan(preference);
        }
    }

    protected void startScan(int preference) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ScanConstants.OPEN_INTENT_PREFERENCE, preference);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getExtras().getParcelable(ScanConstants.SCANNED_RESULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                scannedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);






                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");
                Log.v(TAG, "ExternalStorageDirectory: "+Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                Log.v(TAG, "DATA_PATH: "+DATA_PATH);

                TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
                baseApi.setDebug(true);
                baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
                bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

                String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

                baseApi.end();

                // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with it.
                // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it (if lang is eng)
                // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

                Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

                if ( lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ) {
                    recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] data) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
here's my logcat

```
I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2044(210KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(395KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 242us total 9.669ms
V/MainActivity.java: Before baseApi
V/MainActivity.java: ExternalStorageDirectory: /storage/emulated/0
V/MainActivity.java: DATA_PATH: /storage/emulated/0/ScanDemoExample/
W/linker: libjpgt.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x2114
W/linker: libjpgt.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
W/linker: libpngt.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x4a04
W/linker: libpngt.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2
W/linker: liblept.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x1dc90
W/linker: liblept.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2
W/linker: libtess.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x5d2e8
W/linker: libtess.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x3
E/Tesseract(native): Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng!
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 2863 (om.scanner.demo)
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Did you request the appropriate permissions in the manifest, and did you [request runtime permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)?

Comment: Does logcat show any hint of what went wrong? What's the actual value of `DATA_PATH`? The error message looks like it came from Tesseract; did any of your code's logic report a problem? Did the file(s) get written as you expected (i.e., are they where you expect them to be and Tesseract didn't find them, or are they just not there)?

Comment: I'm using a genymotion emulator if that changes something and I've posted my logcat. I think that the part where the directory is supposed to be created isn't executed at all because I get neither an error indicating it can't be created nor a confirmation of the creation and I even checked to see if it was actually created on the device and it wasn't.

Comment: yes I've got the permissions right in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable this permission?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
```

there is a nice example:
[Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: do I have to do this only with Marshmallow ? 
so what to do for api =<22 ?

Comment: It have to work except old KitKat versions (Google rejected to this 4.4 version at first time, than they fixed this stupid idea)